# SSL Certificate error for mailserver

Tags: ssl, vps, plesk, mail-server

I have a vps with a shared IP. Now, I want use SSL/TLS for the mailserver. I was wondering what kind of certificate I need for the mailserver. So, do I need to issue a certificate on the hostname? because I get an untrusted error in Outlook, if I change the settings. I think this is the same issue as when I log in in the control panel of plesk, I get an error message, that the certificate is not trusted, because it not sign by a CA. I know that plesk issue a self signed certificate. So again. I don't know if I have to issue a certificate on the domain, however I think then i will get also an error, because hostname and domain name are not the same. Can somebody support me?

Comment: You should ask on http://serverfault.com/

Comment: ok thank you for your advice

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You will have to purchase SSL certificate for the hostname, so that your all client will be use your server hostname in mail client setting with the SSL connection

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how I can verify then the hostname. Usually you need an e-mail in the issuing process.